# Christofides Algorithm for the TSP: A "polynomial time approximation algorithm"?

Tags: combinatorics, computer-science, computational-complexity, discrete-optimization, np-complete

I'm currently studying the travelling salesman problem and Christofides algorithm. I think I understand that TSP is an NP-hard problem, and so the complexity of calculating a solution grows exponentially as we add more destinations to the problem.

I'm not well versed in computer science, or computational complexity theory, but upon reading the 'NP-hardness' wikipedia page it says that

"It is suspected that there are no polynomial-time algorithms for NP-hard problems, but that has not been proven."

What I don't get is that Christofides algorithm is considered a polynomial time approximation algorithm, which finds approximations to the optimal solution of the travelling salesman problem. Doesn't this go against the quotation above (i.e. isn't this an example of a polynomial time algorithm being used to solve an NP-hard problem?). Hope this is clear.

Comment: No, this is not an s an example of a polynomial time algorithm being used to solve an NP-hard problem because it does not find an optimal solution but only a near optimal solution. That may be useful for practical problems but does not help to find the optimal solution in polynomial time.

Comment: So basically, we can use a polynomial time algorithm to approximate the solution to an NP hard problem, but not to find the solution itself?

Comment: Yes, but there must not exist polynomial time algorithms for  sufficiently good approximation